# MVC controller unit testing - entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, mocking

I would like to test GetTaskToDo() controller method(i.e check if there is any return result) that take some data from db.

In Unit Test project I added app.config file with connection strings, but after invoking GetTaskToDo() method i get error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException : The underlying provider
>   failed on Open.   ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot
>   attach the file
>   'aspnet-test-20170222081336.mdf'
>   as database 'aspnet-test-20170222081336'.

**MVC Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetTasksToDo()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Tasks>();
            using (Entities dc = new Entities())
            {
                tasks = dc.Tasks.Where(a => a.State == "ToDo").ToList();
                tasks = tasks.OrderBy(a => a.Order).ToList();
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = tasks, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
```

**Simple Unit test:**

```
        [Test]
        public void Test_GetTasksToDo()
        {
            var sut = new HomeController();

            var test = sut.GetTasksToDo();
        }
```

How should I test this? Should I somehow mock entity framework which is used by that method? I'm quite new in this, I would be very grateful for every hint.

Comment: Yes, basically tests should use abstraction instead of initiating EF DbContext. Mocking will give you this flexibility, that you can specify exact values that will be returned everytime you run tests. If database will be offline or data will be corrupted, tests may fail even if logic that you want to test is working correctly.

Comment: Provide app.config's connection string in your unit test project. Testing problem seems triggered from database connection string which unable to get MDF file (should be pointed to same path as web.config in MVC project).